# How to add memory resources to the running pods in kubernetes

Tags: amazon-web-services, memory-management, deployment, kubernetes

I have created 2 replicas of pods using the deployment declarative method in kubernetes by using the following command

```
$ kubectl create -f app-deployment.yaml
```

It created 2 pods of my java web application in one of the node. I want to specify memory resources for those pods. I know that we can specify memory resources to the pods by running the below script.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: app1
spec:
  containers:
  - image: app:v1
    name: app1
    resources:
      limits:
        memory: 300Mi
      requests:
        memory: 200Mi
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
      hostPort: 8082
```

When i run the above script, a new pod with the name app1 gets created with the memory specified.

But how do i specify the memory resources for the pods created using the deployment script which i ran initially ?

Any help on this would be appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the same spec in the `containers` section of your deployment.yaml . The pods will get restarted with the new resource limits.

Comment: I was able to set the memory resources by updating the spec in the existing deployment script. Thank you for your answer..